# Virtualization - Windows guests on Linux host?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, vmware-vsphere, xenserver

Check [my previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/418991/virtualization-for-hardware-resiliency/).

I am now looking at specifics relating to enterprise virtualization. I have done some research into Citrix Xen Server and VmWare vSphere. I need to know whether it is possible to run Windows 2008 guests on linux hosts. I would like to set it up like this for cost reasons.

I am appealing to anyone who has used this setup. What did you think of it? Pros/cons? Performance issues? What distro to use? etc...

Many thanks

Comment: I'm really trying not to be mean, but if you have to ask whether you can run Windows guests on Citrix XenServer or VMWare VSphere then should you really be speccing up an enterprise class virtualisation platform?

Comment: You say you've done research on this -- what has your research told you? Have you tried a Google search for your question title?  We don't mind helping someone who is new to a particular technology, but this isn't a question - it's "Let's discuss the pros/cons/performance of Windows guests on Linux hosts".  Questions need to be concretely answerable - "How do I do X given Y?" or "What are best current practices for Z?". "Tell me your stories" is better suited for chat or traditional forums...

Comment: ESX is Linux.  And lots of people run Windows guests on it.

Comment: It looks like a pretty specific question to me. Just give me a yes/no if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you most definitely can run Windows guests on XenServer and VSphere and almost any other x86 and x64 compatible guest you'd like (If your hardware is 64 bit)

Comment: Seriously though, a question like this indicates you have a LOT of learning to do. Download the free versions, install them on some tin, get some books and start reading previous questions on here. It sounds like you're a long way off being able to spec up and build a virtualisation platform, especially one with shared storage requirements.

You mention cost, but VSphere is by far the most expensive out of Hyper-V, XenServer and VSphere. If you're thinking about using free ESXi then you really need to look up the huge limitations.